# Как добавить по 3 кнопки в каждой строке?

Tags: python, telebot

Есть динамический список. Хочу поделить его по 3 колонки, но не пойму как сделать это. В cats допустим у нас 11 элементов. Логически понятно что на 4 итерации выдаст ошибку, но мне бы понять как в markup запихнуть динамически количество кнопок

```
#делим список cats по 3 колонки
    n = 3
    outList = []
    for i in range(n, len(cats) + n, n):
        outList.append(cats[i-n:i])
    
    for items in outList:
        # btn1 = types.KeyboardButton(items[0])
        # btn2 = types.KeyboardButton(items[1])
        # btn3 = types.KeyboardButton(items[2])
        markup.add(btn1,btn2,btn3)
```

Comment: тоесть 3 колонки и много строчек, а в последней уже сколько останеться? Так?

Comment: @АлексейОсинный да, всё верно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def my_print(number):
    list_buttons = []
    for _ in range(0,number,1):
        list_buttons.append(_)

    print('список кнопок',list_buttons)
    row = []
    column = []
    for i in list_buttons:
        if len(row) < 3:
            row.append(i)
        if len(row) == 3:
            column.append(row)
            row = []
    if len(row) > 0:
        column.append(row)

    print('result:')
    for i in column:#i это строка
        for j in i:#j это столбец
            print(j,' ',end = '')
        
        print()
            
    


my_print(3)
my_print(5)
my_print(7)
my_print(10)
```

если непонятно могу расписать.